# Android BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path) always returns null

Tags: android, bitmap, bitmapfactory

I see that is a lot of solutions related to this issue, but none of this solved my problem.

I try to read image from png file to bitmap (image is very small ~16px so there is no option that I got OutOfMemoryException) using BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path) function.

My file hierarchy is as simple as possible:
-java
--example.com.app
---MainActivity.class
-res
--drawable
---array.png

I launch application from MainActivity and on button click I try to read png image to bitmap.
I try to read image to bitmap in the following ways:

1. `String path = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+R.class.getPackage().getName() +"/drawable/arrow.png").toString();
   Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);`
2. `String path = Uri.parse("android.resource://drawable/arrow.png").toString();
   Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);`

Everytime bitmap is null. Do you know where could be a problem?

Android API 27

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeResource(android.content.res.Resources,%20int)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or use the simple method of `BitmapFactory`

```
BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.id.arrow);
```

Or you can use `context.getDrawable(R.drawable.arrow)` which will return a `drawable` that is ready to use. 
Read more about this [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getDrawable(int))

If you would like to still use the path then use `java.nio.file.Paths(folder1, folder2.. .. .)`
Read more about this [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html)

Answer (score 2):

You should use [decodeResource](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory#decodeResource(android.content.res.Resources,%20int,%20android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options)), below is an example:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.id.arrow, options);
int imageHeight = options.outHeight;
int imageWidth = options.outWidth;
String imageType = options.outMimeType;
```

Or use its simple way [decodeResource](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory#decodeResource(android.content.res.Resources,%20int)).

```
BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.id.arrow);
```

Comment: You are welcome, could you accept my answer, thanks!